# PL/SQL MERGE INTO statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create procedure will move the product (isdiscontinued=1) to another table (Product_discontinued_[NTID]). Structure of the two tables is identical.

```
PROCEDURE move_table AS
 begin
     merge into PRODUCTS_DISCONTINUTED b
     using  PRODUCTS a
     on (a.ID = b.ID)
     when matched then
       update set b.id = a.id,b.productname = a.productname,b.supplierid=a.supplierid,b.unitprice=a.unitprice,
                  b.package=a.package, b.isdiscontinuted=a.isdiscontinuted
        where a.isdiscontinuted = 1
     when not matched then
      insert (id,productname,supplierid,unitprice,package,isdiscontinuted)
      values( a.id,a.productname,a.supplierid,a.unitprice,a.package,a.isdiscontinuted)
      where a.isdiscontinuted = 1; END move_table;
```

I tried to write a procedure to move table PRODUCTS_DISCONTINUTED to PRODUCTS with using MERGE INO statement but it always keep getting the following errors. Could you please help me. Much appreciated.
[enter image description here][2]

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V75mP.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the *text* of your SQL statement or code and the error message. Do not use screenshots.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Terminate `merge` and remove `null;`

```
when not matched then 
  insert ...
  where a.isdicontinuted = 1;       --> semi-colon here
  -- null;                          --> remove this
  end move_table;
```

---

I created tables involved, simply by looking at **code you posted**. Doing so, procedure gets created:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE move_table
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     MERGE INTO PRODUCTS_DISCONTINUTED b
  5          USING PRODUCTS a
  6             ON (a.ID = b.ID)
  7     WHEN MATCHED
  8     THEN
  9        UPDATE SET b.id = a.id,
 10                   b.productname = a.productname,
 11                   b.supplierid = a.supplierid,
 12                   b.unitprice = a.unitprice,
 13                   b.package = a.package,
 14                   b.isdiscontinuted = a.isdiscontinuted
 15                WHERE a.isdiscontinuted = 1
 16     WHEN NOT MATCHED
 17     THEN
 18        INSERT     (id,
 19                    productname,
 20                    supplierid,
 21                    unitprice,
 22                    package,
 23                    isdiscontinuted)
 24            VALUES (a.id,
 25                    a.productname,
 26                    a.supplierid,
 27                    a.unitprice,
 28                    a.package,
 29                    a.isdiscontinuted)
 30             WHERE a.isdiscontinuted = 1;
 31  END move_table;
 32  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

**However**, error you specified:

> ORA-00904: "ISDISCONTINUTED" invalid identifier

means that there's no column whose name is `ISDISCONTINUTED`. Are you sure you didn't make a typo? Compare table description to code in the procedure - I guess there's a mismatch.

Comment: Please, post current code by editing the original question (not as a comment!) so that we'd see what you have.

Comment: thank you for helping but I dont know why it keeps getting error as attached screenshot above when I tried the way of you.

Comment: yesss, you are absolutely right, I made a typo in word "ISDISCONTINUED" instead of ISDISCONTINUTED. Very much appreciated for pointing that out. Thank you !